# where data has been stored between the trans and rollback...?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, rollback

On the interview I faced a question. So I try to recreating it:

**salary**

```
id  Emp_id  Salary
1   1       50000
2   2       40000
3   3       30000
```

See following example:

```
begin tran
update salary set Salary = 25000 where id = 2
select * from salary -- salary = 25000
rollback
select * from salary -- salary = 40000
```

Here my question is,

> where did the old value of salary has been stored.?

Note : My guess is `Magic Table` may be used as like as trigger.

when I googled like 'where did the data has been stored between the trans and rollback', then I get the results as different types of *Transaction-Rollback Tutorials*. So I need helping hand from Stack overflow.

**Edit 1**

```
begin tran
update salary set Salary = 25000 where id = 2
select * from salary -- salary = 25000
-- I want to see salary = 40000 at here. Where as OUTPUT clause is invalid.
rollback
select * from salary -- salary = 40000
```

Thanks,

TamilPugal.

Answer (score 6):

It is NOT a "magic table". The transaction details are stored in the transaction log until the transaction is released (commit or rollback). A table would be insufficient here because a transaction could affect any number of tables.

To be more clear, the data still resides in the table but is marked for deletion. Then either the rows become unmarked or the rows are removed. I am not good at explaining this but that is the basic concept of how it works.

Comment: would it be clearer to say they the data stored in their respective spots until it is committed (left) or rolled back (removed)? I thing the OP is wondering how the data shows up in the select if it was only sitting in the tlog with the transaction details or someother *magic* location

Comment: Okay Sean. I have no knowledge about transaction log. So let me study about it and I will accept your answer. give me a Hi-Fi

Comment: Cool. thanks for the nudge. I know how it works but for some reason that explanation always eludes me. :D

Comment: Well... technically... There are the internal "Inserted" & "Deleted" tables... They may not be magic, but they're pretty darn close to it. And, they do hold the "before & after" data the OP is interested in.

Comment: @JasonA.Long by all means if you can help clarify the explanation please do. And of course we have a language barrier and this was an interview so who knows what the interviewer was really asking. :)

Comment: @SeanLange - The question just made me rethink an onld question. Are "Inserted" & "Deleted" actual tables or simply an easy access to a specific set of LSNs on the transaction log. According to [BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-2017), they are actual, in memory, tables. That said, I don't know how to even test weather or not they materialized as separate objects or simply a convenient window into the transaction log itself.

Comment: So... To tie back to the OP's original question... IF, the output tables are materialized as objects distinct from the transaction log... The "old" (Deleted) rows are written to both the transaction log and the Deleted table.

Comment: I have always looked at them as the convenient window and that is what I was trying to describe. I like your explanation in your last comment quite a bit. Does a nice job explaining it in somewhat simplified terms.

Comment: @SeanLange - Thank you sir. I added a code based answer to illustrate that both the old and new values do infact exist at the same time and both are accessable at the same time.

Comment: @JasonA.Long we have known each other long enough, you don't need to call me sir. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this...

```
USE tempdb;
go

CREATE TABLE dbo.TranTest (id INT NOT NULL, some_value INT NOT NULL);
INSERT dbo.TranTest (id, some_value) VALUES (1, 11111);

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    -- check initial values...
    SELECT * FROM dbo.TranTest tt;

    -- update values and include the OUTPUT clause to view the contents of the "Inserted" & "Deleted" tables.
    UPDATE tt SET 
        tt.some_value = tt.some_value * 22
            OUTPUT 
                Deleted.id, 
                Deleted.some_value, 
                Inserted.id, 
                Inserted.some_value, 
                GETDATE() AS tran_date 
    FROM
        dbo.TranTest tt;

    -- check the values after the UPDATE and before the ROLLBACK
    SELECT * FROM dbo.TranTest tt;

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    -- check the values after the ROLLBACK
    SELECT * FROM dbo.TranTest tt;
```

Results...

```
id          some_value
----------- -----------
1           11111

id          some_value  id          some_value  tran_date
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------------------
1           11111       1           244442      2018-11-16 16:18:17.330

id          some_value
----------- -----------
1           244442

id          some_value
----------- -----------
1           11111
```

Comment: Thank you sir... errr... I mean Sean. :)

Comment: Thanks for visual example. But I think, scope of `output clause` is `null` in out of `update` query. Then how `rollback` gets the old value `11111`..? What you think about @SeanLange answer.

Comment: @IdontKnowEnglish - It certainly not NULL... Understanding how the transaction log works is a fairly in-depth topic. One thing you should understand UPDATE is a bit of a misleading term. It's actually a combined DELETE/INSERT statement and it applies to the entire row, not just the specific column(s) specified in the SET clause. So, when you UPDATE a row, you are deleting the row and then replacing it using an INSERT. The second thing to know is that SQL Server, to be ACID compliant, MUST be able to roll back to a previously steady state if it cannot fully complete a transaction.

Comment: SQL Server does this by using the transaction log. Using the transaction log, SQL Server is able to play back any transaction in reverse, returning to it's previous state. To do that, it must store both the DELETED row and the INSERTED row. So, when you update a row, yes, the old value is deleted and the new value is inserted... BUT... Nothing is permanent until the transaction is "hardened" (aka committed). Rolling back the transaction, causes the transaction to replay all previous actions in reverse, in order to get back to it's previous state.

Comment: You can see this in action by opening a second SSMS tab and executing "SELECT * FROM dbo.TranTest tt;" while the transaction is still open... a) You'll notice that it won't complete, as written, until the UPDATE statement is either committed or rolled back. This is because all other transactions involving those rows are being blocked by the open transaction. Changing it to "SELECT * FROM dbo.TranTest tt WITH (NOLOCK);" will allow the query to ignore the exclusing lock of the still open transaction and read the "uncommitted" values.

Comment: Thanks @JasonA.Long. But I mentioned `null` means, without update query `output` is invalid object. So let me update the question.

Comment: I newly know that `update` is occurs by `deleting/inserting`. And "SELECT * FROM dbo.TranTest tt" is invalid object in SQL'12.

Comment: @IdontKnowEnglish - Output is valid for INSERT and DELETE statements as well. The difference is that UPDATE is the only one of the three that has values in both tables... "SELECT * FROM dbo.TranTest tt"  IS VALID if you run the code in my original answer.